# Design of Scala's class hierarchy. Constructor parameter vs member

Tags: scala, constructor, member

I'm having problems designing the a class hierarchy in scala for a compiler project. The hierarchy looks as follows:

```
abstract class TACInstr(index:Int)

case class TAC_Label(label: String,index : Int) extends TACInstr(index)
case class TAC_Jump(label: TAC_Label,index : Int) extends TACInstr(index)
...
```

Here `index` is a variable that represents the order number of the instruction in some listing. It is important that I cannot declare this variable to be immutable at least for the `TAC_Label` subclass because it is not always predictable in my code what should be its index when it is declared.

Later on I'm using this index value in the following definition:

```
  def getBlock(i : TACInstr) : BasicBlock = 
blocks.find(b => b.instr.index == i.index).get
```

So basically I'm comparing the equality of two indexes of different instructions. This gives the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol index
```

because apparently in this way index is private to the classes definitions

**My approaches**

I tried to declare the hierarchy as follows:

```
abstract class TACInstr(var index:Int)

case class TAC_Label(label: String,override var index : Int) extends TACInstr(index)
case class TAC_Jump(label: TAC_Label,override var index : Int) extends TACInstr(index)
...
```

But I'm obtaining the following error type:

```
Error:... overriding variable index in class TACInstr of type Int;
 variable index cannot override a mutable variable
```

Are there any elegant solutions to this problem? Something better than declaring `index` as a member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to override a field. The examples below solve the problem:

```
// index is public
abstract class TACInstr(var index:Int)

// label is public, i is private
class TAC_Label(val label: String, i: Int) extends TACInstr(i)
class TAC_Jump(val label: TAC_Label, i: Int) extends TACInstr(i)

val l = new TAC_Label("l", 0)
println(l.index)
```

Now with traits

```
trait TACInstr { var index:Int }

case class TAC_Label(label: String, var index: Int) extends TACInstr
case class TAC_Jump(label: TAC_Label, var index: Int) extends TACInstr

val l = TAC_Label("l", 0)
println(l.index)
```

More scala way

```
trait TACInstr { val index:Int }

// label is public, i is private
case class TACLabel(label: String, val index: Int) extends TACInstr
case class TACJump(label: TACLabel, val index: Int) extends TACInstr {
    def withLabelIndex(newIndex: Int): TACJump = this.copy(label = label.copy(index = newIndex))
}

val jump = TACJump(TACLabel("l", 1), 2)
val changed = jump.withLabelIndex(3)
println(changed)
```

This is not the way of writing things in scala. Many smells are: abstract class, var, parent fields. Code in scala not in its design way will only make it hard.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean that your code is a valid solution. In my case the compiler asks for the override modifier for variable which leads to my wrong approach...

Comment: @Javier I have update the code. I think I added enough elements to understand what is happens. Be free to ask if you don't understand anything.